# JPA infinitely recursion with bidirectional relationships in Kotlin and Glassfish

Tags: jpa, kotlin, glassfish, eclipselink

I have 2 data classes in kotlin, each having a reference to eachother. `Profile` and `Kweet` (Code will be at the bottom). When fetching one of these entities with an `EntityManager` it can succesfully fetch a single object. It will never return this however, as the JPA keeps fetching the recursive relationship in the background.

The issue occurs when either `ProfileDao.getById` or `ProfileDao.getByScreenname` is being called.

[Profile.kt](https://github.com/Requinard/s6-jea/blob/master/src/main/kotlin/domain/Profile.kt)

```
@Entity(name = "profile")
@NamedQueries(
(NamedQuery(name = "Profile.getByScreenName", query = "select p from profile p where p.screenname LIKE :screenname")),
(NamedQuery(name = "Profile.getAll", query = "select p from profile p"))
)
data class Profile(
@Id
@GeneratedValue
var id: Int? = null,

var screenname: String,

var created: Timestamp
) {

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "profile", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = [CascadeType.DETACH])
var kweets: List<Kweet> = emptyList()

@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = [CascadeType.DETACH])
@JoinTable(
    name = "liked_kweets",
    joinColumns = [(JoinColumn(name = "profile_id", referencedColumnName = "id"))],
    inverseJoinColumns = [(JoinColumn(name = "kweet_id", referencedColumnName = "id"))]
)
var likes: List<Kweet> = emptyList()

@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = [CascadeType.DETACH])
@JoinTable(
    name = "follows",
    joinColumns = [(JoinColumn(name = "follower_id", referencedColumnName = "id"))],
    inverseJoinColumns = [(JoinColumn(name = "followed_id", referencedColumnName = "id"))]
)
var follows: List<Profile> = emptyList()

@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "follows", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = [CascadeType.DETACH])
var followers: List<Profile> = emptyList()
}
```

[Kweet.kt](https://github.com/Requinard/s6-jea/blob/master/src/main/kotlin/domain/Kweet.kt)

```
@Entity(name = "kweet")
@NamedQuery(name = "Kweet.getAll", query = "select k from kweet k")
data class Kweet(
@Id
@GeneratedValue()
var Id: Int? = null,
var created: Timestamp,
var message: String,
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "profile_id")
@JsonBackReference
var profile: Profile,
@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "likes", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JsonBackReference
var likedBy: List<Profile> = emptyList()
)
```

[ProfileDao.kt](https://github.com/Requinard/s6-jea/blob/master/src/main/kotlin/dao/ProfileDao.kt)

```
@Stateless
class ProfileDao {
@PersistenceContext
lateinit var em: EntityManager

fun getById(id: Int) = em.find(Profile::class.java, id)

fun getAll(): List<Profile> = em.createNamedQuery("Profile.getAll", Profile::class.java).resultList

fun getByScreenname(name: String) = em.createNamedQuery("Profile.getByScreenName", Profile::class.java)
    .setParameter("screenname", name)
    .resultList
    .firstOrNull()

fun create(profile: Profile) = em.persist(profile)

fun follow(follower: Profile, leader: Profile) {
    follower.follows += leader
    leader.followers += follower
    em.persist(follower)
    em.persist(leader)
}
}
```

---

Update: Adding a DTO and marking this as open correctly solves the recursion error. Example:

```
@Open
class ProfileFacade(
private val profile: Profile
) : Serializable {
var screenname: String
    get() = profile.screenname
    set(value) {
        profile.screenname = value
    }

var kweets: List<SimpleKweetFacade>
    get() = profile.kweets.map { SimpleKweetFacade(it) }
    set(value) = Unit

var follows: List<String>
    get() = profile.follows.map { it.screenname }
    set(value) = Unit

var created: Timestamp
    get() = profile.created
    set(value) = Unit
}
```

The `@Open` annotation is a simple `annotation class Open()` which is then processed by gradle to add open and noarg constructors

Comment: And the exception stack trace is...?

Comment: That's the funny thing, there isn't any. It's swallowed by Glassfish, with the error page just giving an error 500

Comment: My guess is that JPA has nothing to do with the problem. JSON serialization is the problem. I'd advise not using the entities (the persistence model) as return type for your REST controller (the communication layer). They contain cycles, and thus JSON serialization navigates recursively through the cyclic graph of entities. And each time you'll modify an entity, you'll also change the API, and potentially expose things that you shouldn't.

Comment: Alright, I'll try that first thing tomorrow!

Comment: Heya, I added a DTO for the profile that only displays the screenname and keeps the actual profile private. Still, it seems that Glassfish and the JPA are recursing on their own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should either use DTOs to represent data in the front end or `@JsonIgnore` parent references from child objects (instead of `@JsonBackReference`).

Using DTOs is probably a smarter choice as you can decouple your front end presentation from the backend model, which gives you flexibility in both layers (ie. changing one layer does not break/possibly introduce bugs in the other).

Comment: Added onto this: The DTO needs to be marked as `open` and needs a no-arg constructor. See the edit in the OP.